# Hudson in constant maintenance mode on Solaris 10

Tags: hudson, solaris

I just installed the latest version of Hudson as a service for Solaris using Paul Oswald's instructions.  Sadly, the service never comes online (always in maintenance mode):

```
# svcs -xv hudson                                
svc:/application/hudson:default (Hudson Continuous Build Server)
 State: maintenance since Mon May 16 07:05:20 2011
Reason: Method failed.
   See: http://sun.com/msg/SMF-8000-8Q
   See: /var/svc/log/application-hudson:default.log
Impact: This service is not running.
```

The log doesn't reveal anything interesting ...

```
# cat /var/svc/log/application-hudson:default.log
[ May 12 12:28:01 Disabled. ]
[ May 12 12:28:01 Rereading configuration. ]
[ May 12 12:28:13 Enabled. ]
[ May 16 07:05:19 Leaving maintenance because clear requested. ]
[ May 16 07:05:20 Enabled. ]
```

Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this issue further, or even better, what the problem is?  I am including my manifest file below.  I have tried restarting the service.  Thanks,  - Dave

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE service_bundle SYSTEM '/usr/share/lib/xml/dtd/service_bundle.dtd.1'>

<!-- 

Copyright (C) 2007 Paul Oswald

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
-->

<service_bundle type="manifest" name="Hudson">
    <service name="application/hudson" type="service" version="1">

            <!-- Initial state of the service is disabled -->
            <create_default_instance enabled="false" />

            <!-- Only one instance of Hudson should ever run per server -->
            <single_instance />

            <dependency name="multi-user-server" type="service" grouping="require_all" restart_on="none">
                    <service_fmri value="svc:/milestone/multi-user-server" />
            </dependency>

            <method_context>
                    <method_credential user='hudson' group='other' />
                    <method_environment>
                            <envvar name='PATH' value='/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/ccs/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sfw/bin' />
                    </method_environment>
            </method_context>

            <!-- Set the HUDSON_HOME env variable, and run the war file in /apps/hudson/hudson.war -->
            <exec_method type="method" name="start" exec="java -Xmx512m -DHUDSON_HOME=/apps/hudson/ -classpath /apps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/ss.jar:/apps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/starteam-sdk.jar:/apps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/starteam110-resources.jar:/apps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/starteam110.jar:/apps/hudson/WEB-INF/lib/swingall.jar -jar /apps/hudson/hudson.war --prefix=/hudson" timeout_seconds="0"/>
            <exec_method type="method" name="stop" exec=":kill -TERM" timeout_seconds="30"/>

            <!-- We are going to be kicking off a single child process so we want Wait mode-->
            <property_group name='startd' type='framework'>
                    <propval name='duration' type='astring' value='child' />
            </property_group>

            <stability value="Unstable" />

            <template>
                    <common_name>
                            <loctext xml:lang='C'>Hudson Continuous Build Server</loctext>
                    </common_name>
                    <documentation>
                            <doc_link name='hudson.dev.java.net' uri='http://hudson.dev.java.net' />
                    </documentation>
            </template>
    </service>
</service_bundle>
```

Comment: If you try to start Hudson from command line -using the "hudson" user- it's runs?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. The issue was - the user name `[hudson]` and the group `[cibuild]` which were configured on the SMF file were not available. I created both of them and then changed the directory `/apps/hudson` ownership to `hudson user` and `cibuild group`. After the change I have restarted the service by disable and enable and then it worked.

To disable use:

> svcadm -v disable hudson

To enable use:

> svcadm -v enable hudson

To check the status:

> svcs -xv hudson